# why can't find a function inside the controller on the server?

Tags: spring-boot, jakarta-ee

i'm creating a controller of the entity "ChaineKO". In this controller i want to add a function which extract data from a file and add them to the DataBase. The extraction works but the recording in the DB does not.

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class ChaineKOContoller {


@Autowired
private ChaineKORepository chaineKORepository;
String pathToFile = "d:\\Profiles\\khbedoui\\Desktop\\Fichier_log__FDCALK2W- 
41343.txt";
ChaineKO chaineKO;

@PostMapping("/ChaineKOAdd")
public void dataExtraction (String pathToFile){

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new 
File(pathToFile)));
        String ligne;

        while((ligne = reader.readLine()) != null){ 
           if(ligne.contains("FP800BOP-BBAO0002-TRAVAIL TRAITE")){

               String matricule = "";
               matricule = ligne.substring(58);
               chaineKO.setMatricule(matricule);

            }

           else if (ligne.contains("FP800BOP-BBAD0003-DEBUT DE 
TRAITEMENT")) {

               String date="";
               date = ligne.substring(64);
               chaineKO.setDate(date);

           }

           else if (ligne.contains("FP800BOP-BBAD0003-DEBUT DE 
TRAITEMENT")) {

               String nomChaine = "";
               nomChaine = ligne.substring(7,11);
               chaineKO.setNomChaine(nomChaine);

           }

           else if (ligne.contains("FIN ANORMALE")){
               chaineKO.setEtat("NON TRAITE");
           }
         }             

    } catch (Exception ex){
        System.err.println("Error. "+ex.getMessage());
    }
    chaineKORepository.save(chaineKO);    
}}
```

And this is my class Repository :

```
@Repository
public interface ChaineKORepository extends JpaRepository<ChaineKO, Long> {

@Query("select e from ChaineKO e where e.nomLog like :x")
public Page<ChaineKO> chercher(@Param("x")String mc,Pageable pageable);
```

}

This is the response when i tested it with postman :

```
    <h1>Not Found</h1>
    <p>The requested URL /8080/ChaineKOAdd was not found on this server.</p>
```

Comment: Read the error message carefully. Look at the path you're requesting. Does it look correct to you?

Comment: Yes it is. the error message contains also this line " <address>Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80</address> " .

Comment: So you mapped your controller to the path "/8080"? Show us your controller declaration.

Comment: I used RestController and CrossOrigin annotations in the declaration of the controller. 
And in the file application.proprities i set the server to "server.port=8080"

Comment: That doesn't tell me how you mapped it. So, once again, Show us your controller declaration. Post the code!

Comment: I edited the post, i added the controller declaration.

Comment: So, you see, it isn't mapped to "/8080". It doesn't have any request mapping at all. So the path for your method should be `/ChaineKOAdd`, and not `/8080/ChaineKOAdd`. Show us the URL you're using to send a request to this method.

Comment: http://localhost/8080/ChaineKOAdd

Comment: If 8080 is supposed to be the **port** or your server, then it should be `localhost:8080/ChaineKOAdd `, not `localhost/8080/ChaineKOAdd`. In the latter, the port is the default port of HTTP (80), and the **path** is `/8080/ChaineKOAdd`.

Comment: Ahh okay thank you Nizet. I corrected the request path, but this time i have this error :
"Target object must not be null; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target object must not be null"
what does this mean ?

Comment: Close or answer this question, and then ask another one, with the complete and exact stack trace of the exception, and the relevant code. But before, **read** the stack trace. It tells you **where** the exception is thrown. And reading the javadoc of the method throwing the exception should help.